# R cmd check note: unable to verify current time

Tags: r

When running `R CMD check` I get the following note:

```
checking for future file timestamps ... NOTE
  unable to verify current time
```

I have seen this discussed [here](https://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/future-time-stamps-warning-td4752612.html), but I am not sure which files it is checking for timestamps, so I'm not sure which files I should look at. This happens locally on my windows and remotely on different systems (using github actions).

Comment: Hmmm... I got exactly the same problem 10 minutes ago.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Take a look at https://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/library/tools/R/check.R
The check command relies on an external web resource:

```
now <- tryCatch({
foo <- suppressWarnings(readLines("http://worldclockapi.com/api/json/utc/now",
                                 warn = FALSE))
```

This resource http://worldclockapi.com/ is currently not available.

Hence the following happens (see same package source):

```
if (is.na(now)) {
   any <- TRUE
   noteLog(Log, "unable to verify current time")
```

See also references:
https://community.rstudio.com/t/r-devel-r-cmd-check-failing-because-of-time-unable-to-verify-current-time/25589

So, unfortunately this requires a fix in the check function by the R development team ... or the web-resource coming online again.

Answer (score 40):

To add to qasta's answer, you can silence this check by setting the `_R_CHECK_SYSTEM_CLOCK_` environment variable to zero e.g `Sys.setenv('_R_CHECK_SYSTEM_CLOCK_' = 0)`

To silence this in a persistent manner, you can set this environment variable on R startup. One way to do so is through the .Renviron file, in the following manner:

1. `install.packages("usethis")` (If not installed already)
2. `usethis::edit_r_environ()`
3. Add `_R_CHECK_SYSTEM_CLOCK_=0` to the file
4. Save, close file, restart R

Comment: How to make this persistent? After I restart RStudio I need to set this again

Comment: Have you ever used the `.Renviron` file? You can set global variables in there that are loaded each time you load RStudio/R.

If you haven't then
1. `install.packages("usethis")`
2. `usethis::edit_r_environ()`
3.  Add `_R_CHECK_SYSTEM_CLOCK_=0` to the file
4. Save, close file, restart R